# Reading value without using sections

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ini

How do I read value from [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) file without using sections?
So instead of normal file:

```
[section]
name=value
```

it would result in this:

```
name=value
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't call it an INI file, then. Anyhow, for this the `TStringList` class fits perfectly.

Consider the file `animals.txt`:

```
dog=Sally
rat=Fiona
cat=Linus
```

And consider this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\animals.txt');
      ShowMessage(Values['dog']);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Nedless to say, if you hate the `with` construct, you can do the very same thing without it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice tutorial [over here](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm). For example, if `iniFile` is an instance of `TIniFile`, you can call the `iniFile.ReadString` method with an empty section specifier.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work. If you call `iniFile.ReadString('', 'VALUE', '');`, it won't find the value and will return an empty string. It seems to require a section or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but here is some code I wrote for my project:

```
function GetPropertyValue(aFile, Key: string): string;
var
  properties: TStringList;
begin
  properties := TStringList.Create;
  try
    properties.LoadFromFile(aFile);
    Result := properties.Values[key];
  finally
    properties.free;
  end;
end;

procedure SetPropertyValue(aFile, Key, Value: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  properties: TStringList;
  found: Boolean;
begin
  found := False;
  properties := TStringList.Create;
  try
    properties.LoadFromFile(aFile);
    for I := 0 to properties.Count -1 do
    begin
      if properties.Names[I] = Key then
      begin
        properties[I] := Key + '=' + Value;
        found := True;
        Break
      end;
    end;

    if not found then
    begin
      properties.Add(Key + '=' + Value);
    end;
  finally
    properties.SaveToFile(aFile);
    properties.free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

***I think the question really needs more information.*** Often people will ask questions relating to *what they think they need to do* instead of asking questions related to what they are actually trying to accomplish.

**Why do you need to do this instead of using the normal methods of reading the ini entries?** 
If these are existing ini files, then you should use the `Tinifile.ReadSections` to read the section names into a stringlist and then iterate through that list using `Tinifile.ReadSectionValues` to read all the section name/values pairs.

**Are you reading existing INI files, or reading and writing your own files?** 
If these are your own files, then Andreas has a good answer above.